# What do I have to learn or should use in creating a 3D android game?

Tags: android, 3d

My thesis is to create an 3D android game. I have installed the 3D softwares like 3DS Max, ZBrush, Blender. I also downloaded Android SDK for Windows and I have Eclipse Juno. But I don't know how to start. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: try cocos3d framework

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to write a game, use a game engine.**
I would advice against using OpenGL directly if you want to focus
on game mechanics or story. 3D game engines like 
[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) or [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/)
give you all the tools you need to turn your 3D assets into a game:
Importers for various file formats, a scene graph,
math libraries, and usually tons of example projects that get you
started quickly.

**If you want to write a rendering engine, use OpenGL**
With OpenGL you can build everything mentioned above yourself: Write
or find importers for your assets, figure out a lighting model, write 
a scene graph. If you want to do all that, cool, use OpenGL. But
doing this technical stuff will keep you busy; you will have less time 
to make a really great game.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) for Android. Good performance and easy enough to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to start from basic with opengl and then understand concept of using 3d and then prefer standard tool to use.

I have listed android game engine tool for 2d and 3d. Hope it might help u.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163446/what-is-the-best-2d-game-engine-for-android/17166794#17166794

Answer (score 0):

Start with unity3d which is a game engine, I am not sure but the names that you have posted are used for making 3d models for the game.

Answer (score 0):

Your Thesis?  That's pretty broad scope! :)

What I would be looking for, is something with lots of example code (since you say you don't know where to start) and good community involvement (ditto the start thing).

If you only need a single player setting, then I would suggest libGDX as a place that would be a good jumping off platform, as there are lots and lots of step thru tutorials along with lots of example code (and a very up to date wiki on the API), and a pretty good group at helping out with issues.

Since it is open source, you can dig as deep as you want into the inner workings to understand (or be mystified like me) as to how the code is accomplishing whatever task you are looking at. (which might be handy for your thesis)

While it might not be quite as polished as some other commercial 3d development kits, the BadLogic crew has made some very big progress the past few months on the 3d side of the house, along with breaking my JSON code... thanks! :) )